# Received NaN for the `children` attribute. If this is expected, cast the value to a string

Tags: reactjs

React newbie here.
I'm trying to decrement the quantity value upon the button click. When I click the button I see a NaN value displayed next to all the buttons. How could I avoid the NaN error? What mistake am I making here and how would I individually update the values on the buttons? Thank you. Data and code follows. [image]

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Python Crash Course",
    "author": "Eric Matthes",
    "quantity": 5
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "Head-First Python",
    "author": "Paul Barry",
    "quantity": 2
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "title": "Invent Your Own Computer Games with Python",
    "author": "Al Sweigart",
    "quantity": 1
  }
```

Below is my React code.

```
class BooksComponent extends Component{

    constructor(){
        super()
        this.state ={
            booksData: []
        }
        this.reserve = this.reserve.bind(this)
    }
    
    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('/library')
          .then(res => {
            const booksData = res.data
            this.setState({ booksData })
          })
    }
    
    render() {
        return (
          <div className="App">
            {this.state.booksData.map(book => {
                const {id, title, author, quantity} = book
                return (
                  <div>
                  <p>{id} - {title} - {author}</p>
                  <button onClick={this.reserve}>Reserve {quantity}</button>
                  <span>{this.state.quantity}</span>
                </div>
                );
            })
            }
          </div>
        )
    }

    reserve(){
        console.log('Reserved')
        this.setState({
            quantity: this.state.booksData.quantity-1
        }
        )
        console.log(this.state)
    }
}



export default BooksComponent
```

Answer (score 6):

The problem is in the reserve funciton.

```
this.state.booksData.quantity - 1
```

`this.state.booksData` is an array and is not possible to access quantity proper.

`this.state.booksData.quantity` is `undefined`

```
undefined - number = NaN
```

You need to filter the array by the id of the bookData item, like this:

```
reserve(id) {
    this.setState({
        quantity: this.state.booksData.find(item => item.id === id).quantity - 1
    })
}
```

And in the onClick pass the id of the bookData item.

> how would I individually update the values on the buttons?

You can try:

```
reserve(id) {
    this.setState({
        booksData: this.state.booksData.map(item => {
            if (item.id === id) {
                return { ...item, quantity: item.quantity - 1};
            } else {
                return item;
            }
        })
    })
}
```

And in the render:

```
<span>{quantity}</span>
```

Comment: Thank you. I have tried using the parseInt but I still see the same error

Comment: Updated! I was wrong Javascript parse the string as an int in the substraction internally

Comment: @NachoZullo you might need to update the setState method b/c at the moment when it runs his state will look like this `state ={booksData = [], quantity = 1}`

Comment: @NachoZullo Thank you! In the render when I use <span>{item.quantity}</span>, the error says 'item' is not defined. How would I define or pass item in the render? Also how to pass the id to onClick?

Comment: @blackPanther I was wrong again :(   its <span>{quantity}</span>. And in the onClick you can do onClick={() => reserve(id)}

Comment: You can define also the reserve as an arrow function and you avoid binding in the constructor. const reserve = () => {// your code here}

Comment: @Nacho Zullo One last thing, how to check if the quantity gets less than 0? Then don't allow to decrement anymore?

Comment: you could do quantity: (item.quantity - 1) >= 0 ? (item.quantity - 1) : 0

Answer (score 0):

You can update the state inline, below is an example:

```
class BooksComponent extends Component{

    constructor(){
        super()
        this.state ={
            booksData: []
        }
        this.reserve = this.reserve.bind(this)
    }
    
    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('/library')
          .then(res => {
            const booksData = res.data
            this.setState({ booksData })
          })
    }
    
    render() {
        return (
          <div className="App">
            {this.state.booksData.map(book => {
                const {id, title, author, quantity} = book
                return (
                  <div>
                  <p>{id} - {title} - {author}</p>
                  <button onClick={()=>this.setState({this.state.booksData: this.state.booksData.map(book => book.id === id ? book.quantity - 1 : book)})}>Reserve {quantity}</button>
                  <span>{this.state.quantity}</span>
                </div>
                );
            })
            }
          </div>
        )
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally (from a higher level) you want to revise your state, and how it is updated. In most cases, your `initialState` has an `undefined` value, and calculations in the `subscriber` are being done using the undefined value.

For my case though, I had initial state defined in the `reducer` and the `subscriber` had the default value (initially), but a dispatched action in `componentDidUpdate` (from one of the earlier re-renders in the `publisher`) would reassign the said value to undefined (hence the warning is thrown in the console). However, later re-renders (when the network request is successful) would dispatch an action to reassign with an actual value!

Messy state management, but you get the point! What I did was to add an equality check for `prevState` and `this.state` for the particular fields, and the error was resolved. I later improved my state management to avoid such complexity.